# How to use functional component from parent to child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Hello I am very new to react.js.

I would like to create function in child component and use it in parent component.

In parent component,

```
import ListReport from './Child';
...
  <ListReport dataval={Dfprocess} />
```

and here is child component.

```
const ListReport = (props) => {
  const dataval = props;

  const keys1 = [];
  for (const item of dataval){
    for (const var1 of Object.keys(item)){
      keys1.push(var1)
    }
  };
  ...
  return (
    ...
    {<thead>
       <tr>
         {keys1.map(key => <th key={key}>{key}</th>)}
       </tr>
     </thead>}
     ...
  );
```

However this code fires error with

**TypeError: dataval is not iterable**

I expect dataval as list and when I define dataval in child components like below, there will be no error...

```
  const dataval = [
    {'Subject': ['100', '101', '102']},
    {'Height': [189, 200, 174]},
    {'Country': ["Japan", "US", "India"]},  
    {'Type': ["A", "B", "C"]}
  ]
```

I think passing argument is not working in my code, could you please let me know how to fix this issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should move that for loop in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) as it blocks function and delays render.

next learn about [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and other [ES6 features](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features)

1. you can destructure props like this

```
const ListReport = ({dataval}) => {
  const dataval = props;
```

2. get the property from props

```
const ListReport = (props) => {
  const dataval = props.dataval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should are passing in `dataVal` as a named prop, but are forgetting to destructure it on the `ListReport` like so `const ListReport = ({dataVal)`

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very fundamental mistake..